# How to create a Ionic 2 android application with the same angular 2 website ?

Tags: android, cordova, typescript, angular, ionic2

Hello Everybody i have a question about ionic 2 and angular 2

#### Can i convert a angular2 website to be a ionic 2 android application with the same components , the same interfaces and the same code ?

Help Please?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you need is Cordova: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova

1. Create Cordova app
2. Copy your app code inside cordova.app/www directory
3. Build your apk